# JSON Validator not validating the schema in Mule

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I am have a following JSON schema which I am trying to validate using JSON Schema validator

JSON Schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07schema#",
    "description": "Create Orders Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "default": "United States of America",
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
  }
}
```

When I am passing the wrong postal_code pattern for country "Canada", it is not validating and it passes through.

Invalid payload:

```
{
  "street_address": "24 Sussex Drive",
  "country": "Canada",
  "postal_code": "10000"
}
```

Am I missing something or JSON validator doesn't support the conditional if-then-else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the schema uses the Draft 7 JSON Schema specification. The documentation of the connector says that the [validate schema operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/json-module/2.1/json-reference#validateSchema) only supports draft 3 or 4:

> This connector supports JSON Schema Validation Drafts 3 and 4 only.

Comment: Thanks for the response.The if-then-else condition is available in Draft 7. Is there any other alternative for if-then-else to check the value and accordingly set the property of other field?

Comment: if-then-else was added in draft 7. You can try to replace with implications as described at: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#implication

Comment: Tried same example given in the Implication, but looks like JSON Validator is not working as expected (as mentioned in the link, it is failing even in the valid scenario)

Comment: Did you declare the example to be using Draft 04? `http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#`

Comment: Yes, tried with Draft 04, still it is failing in valid scenario.

Comment: I suggest to open a new question for that issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have opened a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021510/mule-json-validator-ignoring-implication-to-validate